# How do I retrieve all column fields as objects from Tabulator?

Tags: json, string, javascript-objects, tabulator

I want to make the custom filter dynamic. So, for writing future code I could pass in a list of references to each field object in the table.

That way I do not have to hardcode data.(field name here). Instead, it would work off the list of properties of the column object.

I know there ways to get the field normally but they are always returned as strings not object references. This obviously will not work with the dot operator.

I have some success with using JSON.parse followed by looping through the entries. But like before it returns the field as a string instead of a reference.

So is there a way to retrieve the column fields as objects and if so how?

I tried using the getColumns but I am still getting undefined when grabbing the fields. There is something wrong with my code.

```
 function customFilter(data, filterParams) {
    //data - the data for the row being filtered
    //filterParams - params object passed to the filter

    for (column of table.getColumns()){
        field = column.getField();
        console.log(data.field);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You speak about references in your question, but references to what? the field names themselves arent references to anything, they simply show Tabulator how to access the underlying row data, without a specific row data object to reference, there isn't anything to build any references from

You can only have a reference if it points to something, but there is nothing for the field definitions to point to without the row data.

If you are looking to have objects that you can manipulate the the ***getColumns*** function returns an array of [Column Components](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/components#component-column) with each component having a range of functions that can be called to manipulate that column. including the ***getField*** function that returns the field for that column.

Given that the Tabulator filter functions will accept the filed names with dot notation that shouldnt be an issue at all, but you can also pass the column component directly into the filter, so it shouldnt be a problem their either

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.  In my original question, I added what I think the code might look like. Could you let me know if that's correct?

Comment: The issue there is that you are console logging data.field. if you want to access the field of the data object using the field variable it should be data[field]

Comment: I tried that it worked. So, thanks for your help. I am not too experienced with Object-Oriented Programming in Javascript. Why did the dot operator not work and I had to index the field from the data object?

Comment: Because the dot operator is instructing it to look for the property of "field" on the data object, it is treating it as the string field not the variable (there would be no way for the system to know you wanted to use a variable there) who h is why you have to pass it in as an index. They are just different ways of accessing things on objects, bot dot notation and square braces are valid but you have to pass variables in braces